# How to invoke the two different java scripts without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I got stuck with the following scenario like I have two timers. If user logins and if he takes up any task to do he has to mention the estimation time for the completing the task. When the estimation time is mentioned and task is started in my application a count down timer runs which is a java script and decrements finally coming to 00:00:00:00 when the first timer comes to 00:00:00:00 the second timer starts like it increments from the end of estimation time given by the user. I used reload.location(true) where if the timer one becomes 00:00:00:00 my page gets refreshed once and we can see the second timer. But I want to load the second timer without refreshing the page. For the reference I'm pasting the code from my application. Please help me out is there any way of invoking the second javascript without refreshing the page.

In my show.rhtml: I have written the following code

```
<%# Added by RE4 - Countdown Timer %>

  <% if (User.current == @issue.assigned_to) || User.current.admin? %>

        <h3><%= "Time Left" %></h3>

        <%= javascript_include_tag('timer.js') %>

        <%= render :partial => "issues/countdown_timer", :locals => {:issue => @issue} %>

  <% end %>

  <div style="font-size: 30px;">

        <div id="countdown_timer"></div>

    </div>

  <%# Countdown timer end %>



 <%# Countdown Timer for exceeded time %>

  <% if (User.current == @issue.assigned_to) || User.current.admin? %>

      <h3><%= "Exceeding Time" %></h3>

           <%= javascript_include_tag('timer_two.js') %>

           <%= render :partial => "issues/exceeded_countdown_timer", :locals => {:issue => @issue} %>

 <% end %>

  <div style="font-size: 30px; color: red;">

        <div id="exceeded_countdown_timer"></div>

    </div>


end
```

As you can see in the above code I'm rendering two partials one is _countdown_timer and _exceeded_countdown_timer.In Code regarding to partials I'm calculating days,hours,seconds minutes and passing the values to the two timers

in _countdown_timer.rhtml:

```
<script>

    window.onload = init;

    function init()

    {

    timer.init(@days,@hours,@minutes, @seconds,'countdown_timer');

    }

  </script>
```

In the same way in _exceeded_countdown_timer.rhtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = init2;

    function init2()

    {

     timer_two.init(@days,@hours,@minutes,@seconds,'exceeded_countdown_timer');

    }

    </script>
```

From the above code in the both the partials continuously for every sec I'm passing the values of days,hours,minutes,seconds so that my timer works even we refresh the page. From the show page I'm invoking the this two partials, where in turn this partials calls the timers depending up on the condition. The code related to two timers is
Timer_one.js

```
if(timer.hours == 0)

 {

   if(timer.days == 0)

    {

       location.reload(true)

       clearInterval(timer.samay);

       timerComplete(this.elm);

        return;

    }

  else

  {

    timer.seconds=60;

    timer.minutes=59;

    timer.hours=23;

    timer.days--;

  }

}
```

so as you can see both timer_one.js

When the values are becoming zero I'm invoking `location.reload(true)` where page gets refreshed so that the second timer is visible. But I don't want this to happen. When first timer comes to 00:00:00:00 the second timer should start automatically without refreshing the page.

Please help me out. Any kind of help is welcome.

Comment: Initially My question was submitted incompletely now I have added the accurate information. Please take a look it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to get the start time and estimated time, then at any point you can calculate the time left or exceded.

Then you just need one timer that displays the time remaining until it reaches zero, then also display the time overrun.

Comment: I'm sorry  i didn't get you. Actually i have implemented 2 timers one decrements and the other increments. Everything is fine and working. As you can see in timer.js I'm using reload.location(true) so it refresh that page so that after estimated time is complete i can see the second timer. In other words presently, when the estimation time is completed a refresh is need to see the second timer. But i don't want to do that refreshing. Without refreshing when time estimated is complete i want the second timer should be started.